# SIGSEGV on huge array on heap (I think so)

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

Have problem with sigsegv with huge array. As I find it often is problem with allocating on stack. But I'm allocating this array on heap and still got SIGSEGV. I'm not sure what is wrong.

```
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

#define DATA_SIZE 1000000

static int inputArray[DATA_SIZE];

int* CountOnes(int* data)
{
    int outputArray[DATA_SIZE];
    int count, i;

    for (i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; i++)
    {
        count = 0;
        while (*(data + i) > 0)
        {
            if (*(data + i) & 0x01)
                count++;

            *(data + i) >>= 1;
        }
        outputArray[i] = count;
    }
    return outputArray;
}

int main()
{
    CountOnes(inputArray);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried allocating with static global array, global array, array allocated with new. Any ideas?

Comment: `static int inputArray[DATA_SIZE]` is not allocating on the heap. To do so you need a `malloc` or a `new`. `int outputArray[DATA_SIZE]` within a function is almost _certainly_ on the stack, hence your blowout.

Answer (score 1):

Your `outputArray` is still allocated on the stack. Use `ulimit -s unlimited` to remove the default stack size limit. Also note that you are returning a pointer to a stack array from `CountOnes`. That won't work since the array is destroyed on exit from the function and therefore the pointer returned becomes invalid. You should either make `outputArray` static or allocate it with the `new` operator.

Comment: Oh... yeah, outputArray, indeed. I missed this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> As I find it often is problem with allocating on stack.

Indeed, on most platforms the stack is quite small (typically from a few dozen kilobytes up to a few megabytes), and can easily overflow if you create large automatic objects. Specifically, `outputArray` is (probably) four megabytes, which (probably) is too large.

> I tried allocating with static global array, global array, array allocated with new.

Any of those should work, but have other issues - static arrays (local or global) prevent reentrancy and thread-safety, and `new` requires you to jump through hoops to correctly delete the array. The best option is `std::vector<int>`, a dynamic array which manages its (heap-allocated) memory automatically.